# How can I see my mac address on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-address

How can I see my mac address on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Update**

As described in the newer answer below, the modern solution is to run:

```
ip addr show
```

The MAC address is shown in the `link/ether` field.

**Original Answer**

Open a terminal and run ifconfig:

```
ifconfig | grep HWaddr
```

Comment: by the way, do you know what the "if" of "ifconfig" stands for?

Comment: ifconfig is short for "Interface Configurator"

Answer (score 41):

Use `ip` command instead of the [outdated](https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig) `ifconfig`

**Command** :

`$ ip addr show`

`link/ether` field of the output is the MAC address (Both for Wi-fi and ethernet connections, MAC address is represented by `link/ether`). Mostly this will be present in the second line.

**Example :**

```
$ ip addr show
1: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:54:9f:53:b2:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

In my case `a0:54:9f:53:b2:6e` is the MAC address.

Comment: By the way, just `ip a` works too, but the longer syntax is more clear.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS, there is no `HWaddr` in the output from `ifconfig`. Instead, look at `ether`:

```
$ ifconfig | grep ether
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [ifconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig), and look at the "HWaddr".

Answer (score 2):

okay, this is a very easy solution.
1/ Open a terminal
2/ ifconfig
A list of network capable devices will be displayed.
If you are using wireless, it usually is called wlan0, but can also be named pan0 wifi0 etc.
A physical conection is most likely eth0.
on the first line you will see your mac address. here is a sample of what you might see
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00

that's it.

You can spoof your mac address too with macchanger (sudo aptitude install macchanger) 
just type man macchanger to learn more

Answer (score 2):

You can also right-click on the GNOME Network Manager. There you choose connection information and the following window shows you the hardware address. See also [NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager0.7) at Ubuntus Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `ip a` won't show the physical mac address. i.e. if you're using a bond interface.

[ethtool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ethtool.8.html) can be used to show the permanent mac address.

```
$ sudo ethtool -P eno2
Permanent address: b8:cb:29:aa:aa:aa
```

Where `eno2` is your interface name.

Comparing this to the command used in other answers:

```
$ ip a sh dev eno2
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:0f:e0:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```